# Error opening "Electron" on Mac OS Big Sur 11.2.3. What to do?

Tags: macos, electron

[it says, "i cant open electron cuz its damaged. we recommend you put it in the trashbin.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU0bV.png)

installed it as described:
=> node.js first
=> then: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null ; brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask 2> /dev/null
=> then:brew cask install electron
terminal didn't know cask, so i left it out and just put in "brew install electron"
=>install completed, no problems detected

=> try to open then i get the error message in the picture added

=>already tried to open right click context menu and open, same error
=>already disabled gatekepper via terminal, same error

Pls help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure to [edit] your question to solve the currently very severe formatting issues in order to make it more intelligible. Also, Electron is a *framework* for *writing apps*, not an Application itself. (I don't use macOS, but it could be that that's the root cause of the problem.) What were you trying to do with it?

Comment: Thanks Alexander! Is there any page for guidlines so I can avoid makin so many formatting misstakes, pls hlp i am new to this. I am doing a training as a specialist for apps development in Germany. Did a project with c# and wcf. asked my tutor about learning WPF and he said skip it and look at electron, because it is cross functional and more modern than WPF. Here I am.. and can't get it runnin.. it is a course programm about safe file sharing for family documents like birth certificates etc.

Comment: As for formatting, take a look at the [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also, it's a good start to first consult Electron's [documentation and tutorials](https://www.electronjs.org/docs#learning-the-basics) and specifically the [Quick Start Guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start). This should teach you the basics and for everything more sophisticated, there are tons of tutorials available on the internet. However, this is a comprehensive framework and without any guidance whatsoever pretty difficult to tackle.

Comment: Thank you very much for the links. Looks I have some studying to do and will get some formatting skills as well on the way.

Comment: Yes, Electron is an NPM module so first you'd need to install Node.js and NPM then install Electron through NPM with: `npm install -g electron`.

Comment: Hi Joshua, thx for the help. Will try again!!